# Finding Minimum Value Error In 2D vector iteration

Tags: c++, vector, iteration, 2d, minimum

//Max function is working as intended while the minElev is inserting a huge negative value when it hits the final column of the first row.  Not sure what is going on and how to fix....

```cpp
bool pathfinder::_read_data(string data_file_name) {
    string string_1 = "", string_2 = "";
    int rows = 0, columns = 0;
    int x = 0;   //Temp Variable
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    ifstream fileIn(data_file_name);
//    if (!fileIn) {
//        cerr << "Couldn't read this file!!!";
//        return 666;
//    }

    fileIn >> string_1 >> columns >> string_2 >> rows;


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

            fileIn >> x;
            temp.push_back(x);

        }
        a.push_back(temp);
        temp.clear();
    }
    int maxElev = a[0][0];
    int minElev = a[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
            if(a[i][j] > maxElev){
                maxElev = a[i][j];
            }
            if(a[i][j] < minElev){
                minElev = a[i][j];
            }
        }

    }



    // TODO: read in and store elevation data

    // TODO: close input file

    // TODO: return true if everything worked
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is the matrix a square? If not `a.size()` probably won't cut it for both dimensions. Depending on what `a` is, `a.size()` might not cut it at all. Hard to say for sure what exactly is wrong here. This code might be perfect and you have a small army of dancing gremlins wrecking havoc a few lines before the code you've shown us starts. You can probably salvage this question with a [mre].

Comment: Posted below hopefully that makes it more clear? :)

Comment: Much more clear. `for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)` needs to be `for(int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)`. This will run `j` from zero to the size of the row `vector` stored at at `a[i]`, whatever size it is.

Comment: And there's me breaking the rules and answering in a comment. One moment, please...

Answer (score 0):

`j` looks like it's allowed to go out of bounds. Crom only knows what value the program will read if it is outside the storage allocated to the `vector`, if it reads anything at all. To prevent this

```
for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
```

needs to be changed to

```
for(int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
```

This change will run `j` from zero to the size of the row `vector` stored at at `a[i]`.

Comment: THANK YOU so very much!